Prisma cannot find the required `libssl` system library in your system. Please install openssl and try again
I am using a nextjs project in the dev.idx ide and getting this error. Can't find any solution anywhere, i tried to install openssl using npm i openssl , but that didn't work.
Error fetching products: PrismaClientInitializationError:
Invalid prisma.product.findMany() invocation:
Unable to require(/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/.prisma/client/libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node).
Prisma cannot find the required libssl system library in your system. Please install openssl and try again.
Details: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at In.handleRequestError (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:7177)
at In.handleAndLogRequestError (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:6211)
at In.request (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:122:5919)
at async l (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:127:11167)
at async GET (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/product/route.ts:41:26)
at async /home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63809
at async eU.execute (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53964)
at async eU.handle (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:65062)
at async doRender (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1315:42)
at async cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1537:28)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1445:28)
at async DevServer.renderPageComponent (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1842:24)
at async DevServer.renderToResponseImpl (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1880:32)
at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:893:25)
at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:269:17)
at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:789:17)
at async /home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:331:20
at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:151:20)
at async DevServer.handleRequest (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:328:24)
at async invokeRender (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:174:21)
at async handleRequest (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:353:24)
at async requestHandlerImpl (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:377:13)
at async Server.requestListener (/home/user/realtime-private-chat-nextts/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:140:13) {
clientVersion: '5.14.0',
errorCode: undefined
}

libssl is required
so in case of docker you have 2 options:

use docker image with already installed libssl, like 'node:20'
install it manually via RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl

